# Do action while long click

Tags: java, android

Hello I am trying to perform some actions while the user is holding down a button.

My problem is that my `Runnable` wont "run".

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        final Runnable r = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() 
            {//do the forwarding logic here

                int test = 0;

                if(holdingDown)
                    test++;
                else
                    return;

                Log.i("test", test+"");
            }
        };

        r.run();

        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            {
                holdingDown= false;
                Log.i("holdingDown", "false");
                break;
            } 
        }   
        return false;
    }
```

The `onTouch` is for detecting when the user stop pressing the button. When I look at my logs I see at that the `Runnable` runs only once.

My test log get only the value 1.

The log call for `Log.i("holdingDown", "false")` is getting triggered at the right time, only when I stop touching the button.

Why is it that my `Runnable` won't run? Thanks.

EDIT:

I tried this code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        holdingDown = true;

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                      if(holdingDown)
{
            int test = 0;   
            test++;
            Log.i("test", test+"");
}
else 
return;


            }
        }).start();

        return false;
    }
```

Its till not working.

Comment: where are you changing to true the value of `holdingDown`? Also, that's not the way to start and run a thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a Thread instead of a Runnable like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         //code you want to run on long press
     } };

thread.start();
```

OR

You could try putting the Runnable inside a Thread like this:

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // code you want to run on long press
        }
    });

thread.start();
```

UPDATE: - try this?

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    holdingDown = true;

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (holdingDown) {
                int test = 0;
                test++;
                Log.i("test", test + "");
            } else {
                Log.i("test", "else");
            }
                return;

        }
    }).start();

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't do `r.run()` to start a thread, that only runs it once.

You either do `new Thread(r).start();` or you use a `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class called `HoldingDown` overriding `Runnable` and instantiate a `Thread` object passing a new instance of your `HoldingDown` and call the start method.

Also, you can use the `mousePressed` and `mouseReleased` events of `MouseListener`.

You should start a new `Thread` in your `mousePressed`, store the instance somewhere and stop it on `mouseReleased`.

See the documentation for more details.